# How can my view respond to a mousewheel?

Tags: android, mouse

I have a view with an `onTouch` that can distinguish between touch input and left/middle/right mouse clicks, as in

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getButtonState() == MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY) // API 14 required
    ...
  ...
}
```

I'd also like this view to respond to the mousewheel.  `onTouch` is not the way, nor have I found any other event handler to respond to the mousewheel.  Maybe the view can pretend to be scrollable and do its own thing with scrolling methods?  At this point, I've given up, and am using keyboard input (1 through 9, plus 0) to select displayed elements that I'd prefer to select with the mousewheel.
So a firm hint or a bit of code would be appreciated.

Don't worry that an Android UI requiring a keyboard and mouse will be inflicted on the public; the app is a development tool.

EDIT: the correct answer is given below, but just so this question is more helpful to future readers, this is (slightly edited) the actual code that I'm using as a result:

```
@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (0 != (event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER)) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
        if (event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL) < 0.0f)
          selectNext()
        else
          selectPrev();
        return true;
    }
  }
  return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps get a key event, like pageup or something?  GoogleTV has those keyboards, but all I can find talks about d-pad, not scroll wheel.

Comment: @jeffamaphone, `Toast.makeText(this, "ke:" + KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` produces nice output in the activity's `onKeyDown`.  It's silent when I manipulate the mousewheel.

Comment: You should answer your own question to mark it as answered - and also get some points :)

Comment: @atok, I did accept an answer, but it seems to have disappeared.  It was just a document link.

Comment: upvote for answer within the question.

Comment: You should put your answer in an answer. Otherwise this question appears on the unanswered list.

Comment: Great question and answer. Thank you. BTW, please put the answer as an answer and accept it. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The accepted answer was a document link that led me to the example code in the question, but that answer was deleted.  So that this question no longer appears 'unanswered', this is how your view can respond to a mousewheel:

```
@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (0 != (event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER)) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
        if (event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL) < 0.0f)
          selectNext();
        else
          selectPrev();
        return true;
    }
  }
  return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mouse wheel event action is considered a scroll event