# how to detect bluetooth mouse wheel being up or down on android app

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to detect bluetooth mouse wheel changes,and I know what's the actionCode for mouse wheel changes,but don't know it's being up or down.

```
    public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {
        //how to detect mouse wheel being up or down?
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer can be found in this question: [How can my view respond to a mousewheel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024809/how-can-my-view-respond-to-a-mousewheel)

I have copied the code sample from there:

```
@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (0 != (event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER)) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
        if (event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL) < 0.0f)
          selectNext()
        else
          selectPrev();
        return true;
    }
  }
  return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
}
```