# How can I capture mouse wheel events in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am writing an Android app, for use on a Chromebook, that uses a google map.

I can enable map zooming controls and I can also enable "pinch" gestures that will zoom the map in or out.

What I would like to do is allow the user's mouse wheel to zoom the map in and out as well.

Does Android have a way to listen for mouse wheel events?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. I will post my code as an answer. Thanks Morrison!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user Morrison Chang pointing out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024809/how-can-my-view-respond-to-a-mousewheel) that had the answer.

I attached an OnGeneralMotion handler in the Map fragment's OnCreatewView override:

```
        rootView.setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
            //
            // Listen for mouse wheel events. 
            @Override
            public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (0 != (event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER)) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                            if (event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL) < 0.0f)
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
                            else
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
                            return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but i think you can achieve this by using this code snippet.

```
@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 if (0 != (event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER)) {
  switch (event.getAction()) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
     //your code here
    return true;
   }
 } 
 return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
```

}